# In Bash, how to convert number list into ranges of numbers?

Tags: arrays, bash, numbers, range

Currently I have a sorted output of numbers from a command:

> 18,19,62,161,162,163,165

I would like to condense these number lists into a list of single numbers or ranges of numbers

> 18-19,62,161-163,165

I thought about trying to sort through the array in bash and read the next number to see if it is +1...   I have a PHP function that does essentially the same thing, but I'm having trouble transposing it to Bash:

```
foreach ($missing as $key => $tag) {
    $next = $missing[$key+1];
    if (!isset($first)) {
        $first = $tag;
    }
    if($next != $tag + 1) {
        if($first == $tag) {
            echo '<tr><td>'.$tag.'</td></tr>';
        } else {
            echo '<tr><td>'.$first.'-'.$tag.'</td></tr>';
        }
        unset($first);
    }
}
```

I'm thinking there's probably a one-liner in bash that could do this but my Googling is coming up short....

**UPDATE:**
Thank you @Karoly Horvath for a quick answer which I used to finish my project.  I'd sure be interested in any simpler solutions out there.

Comment: "but I'm having trouble transposing it to Bash" - which parts do you have problems with?

Comment: Do you want to launch a code golf for this one? `:-)`

Comment: @KarolyHorvath the problems I have are with getting the list into an array, iterating over an array and outputting, just don't know the syntax very well.

Comment: then don't use an *array*. you can 1) read them one by one 2) don't try to read the next value, rather remember the old one. `sed "s/,/\n/g"`

Comment: in bash `[` is a command, so it requires a space afterwards. Also, special syntax is needed for arithmetic: `if [ $prev -ne $((n+1)) ]` or `if (( prev != n+1 ))`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, shell does variable substitution, if `prev` is not set, that line becomes:

```
if [ -ne $n+1]
```

Here is a working version:

```
numbers="18,19,62,161,162,163,165"

echo $numbers, | sed "s/,/\n/g" | while read num; do
    if [[ -z $first ]]; then
        first=$num; last=$num; continue;
    fi
    if [[ num -ne $((last + 1)) ]]; then
        if [[ first -eq last ]]; then echo $first; else echo $first-$last; fi
        first=$num; last=$num
    else
        : $((last++))
    fi
done | paste -sd ","

18-19,62,161-163,165
```

Comment: Might I recommend `tr` instead of `sed` for single-character translations? `tr , '\n'` (For that matter, you could use parameter expansion and skip the subshell.)

Comment: @kojiro: yepp, that would work. (Honestly, if I write shell script, I never worry about performance.. if it was important, I would have chosen a different language. BTW I would never implement this in shell script, but hey, that's what the OP asked for :)

Comment: How about use `IFS=,` instead of `sed`?

Comment: @xiaoyi Yes, or just put the numbers in an array to begin with and use `for`.

Comment: great script! For a number list that is line-separated instead of comma-separated (typical if you're handling tables), keep an extra newline at bottom of the list file, and replace the first two commands as so: ```cat numbers.txt | while .... ```