# Create a file according to sort contend

Tags: bash, awk

I have a list of more than 100000 records.

per example the values from 21 to 84 are continuous, then it will be 21-84 but if it is not continuous as the case 84 87, then it need to be 84,87 separated by ,
at beginning of each line will be the value 11111.

The values from the list will be in the column range of 21 to 80 with, at last.

The length of each row need to be maximum 80.

here is the input file.

```
  21
  22
  23
  24
  25
  26
  27
  28
  29
  30
  31
  32
  33
  34
  35
  36
  37
  38
  39
  40
  41
  42
  43
  44
  45
  46
  47
  48
  49
  50
  51
  52
  53
  54
  55
  56
  57
  58
  59
  60
  61
  62
  63
  64
  65
  66
  67
  68
  69
  70
  71
  72
  73
  74
  75
  76
  77
  78
  79
  80
  81
  82
  83
  84
  87
  85
  86
  88
  89
  90
  91
  92
  93
  94
  95
  96
  97
  98
  99
 100
 101
 102
 103
 104
 105
 106
 108
 111
 109
 112
 110
 113
 115
 114
 117
 116
 118
 124
 125
 120
 122
 123
 126
 132
 127
 133
 128
 130
 131
 135
 136
 137
 138
 139
 140
 141
 142
 143
 144
 145
 146
 148
 147
 149
 150
 151
 152
 153
 154
 155
 156
 158
 157
 159
 160
 161
 162
 163
 164
 165
 166
 167
 168
 169
 170
 171
 172
 173
 174
 175
 176
 177
 178
 179
 180
 181
 182
 184
 183
 185
 186
 187
 188
 189
 190
 191
 192
 193
 194
 195
 196
 197
 198
 199
 200
 201
 202
 203
 204
 205
 206
 207
 208
 209
 210
 211
 212
 214
```

here in the output file desired.

```
111111              21-84,87,85-86,88-106,108,111,109,112,110,113,115,114,117,
111111              116,118,124-125,120,122-123,126,132,127,133,128,130-131,
111111              135-146,148,147,149-156,158,157,159-182,184,183,185-212,214,
```

thanks in advance

Comment: What is the problem?  What didn't work?

Comment: Hi karakfa, I still thinking how to do the code to create the output file desired. i did it manually as example till I  got the main idea how to do the code,

Comment: See: [In Bash, how to convert number list into ranges of numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13708705/3776858)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presented without explanation: check the man pages for the commands used and come back with questions:

```
awk '
    function printrange() { print start (start == last ? "" : "-" last) }
    NR == 1 {start=last=$1; next} 
    $1 == last+1 {last=$1; next} 
    {printrange(); start=last=$1}
    END {printrange()}
' file | paste -sd" " | fold -sw 60 | tr ' ' ',' | sed 's/^/111111              /'
```

```
111111              21-84,87,85-86,88-106,108,111,109,112,110,113,115,114,117,
111111              116,118,124-125,120,122-123,126,132,127,133,128,130-131,
111111              135-146,148,147,149-156,158,157,159-182,184,183,185-212,214
```

Comment: Hi Glenn.. awesome code. kindly can you explain a bit how the code works?. The process before END and the commands paste -sd and fold -sw 60. Appreciate your comments.

Comment: I will encourage you to use your imagination, and think about that awk code yourself: what happens when it reads the 1st line? The 2nd? What happens when it get to the "87" line? And the line after that?

Comment: I will encourage you to run the pipeline piece by piece to see how each command affects the output of the previous. Run the awk code by itself. Then add the paste command. Then add the fold command. Etc. Read the man pages and see what those options are for.

Comment: Hi Glenn., I will try and understand the code..appreciate your help