# Convert number list to range in multiple fileds in a table using bash

Tags: bash

I have a file with two columns of number lists, and need to convert them to ranges. Looking for a bash command line to achieve that. Thanks in advance!

Input file: 
col1 col2 col3 col4 
a 1,2,3,5 b 11,12,13,14 
c 3,5,6 d 13,16,17 
f 6 g 1,2,3,4 
... ... ... ... ...

Output file: 
col1 col2 col3 col4 
a 1-3,5 b 11-14 
c 3,5-6 d 13,16-17 
f 6 g 1-4 
... ... ... ... ...

```html
<p>I have a file with two columns of number lists, and need to convert them to ranges. Looking for a bash command line to achieve that. Thanks in advance!</p>
<p>Input file: <br />col1&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; col2&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; col3 &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; col4 <br />a &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 1,2,3,5&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; b&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 11,12,13,14 <br />c&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 3,5,6&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; d&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 13,16,17 <br />f&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; 6&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; g&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 1,2,3,4 <br />...&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; ...&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; ...&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; ... </p>
<p>Output file: <br />col1&nbsp;&nbsp; col2&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; col3&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; col4 <br />a&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 1-3,5&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; b&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 11-14 <br />c&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 3,5-6&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; d&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 13,16-17 <br />f&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 6&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; g&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 1-4 <br />...&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; ...&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; ...&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; ...</p>
```

Comment: I can't think of a unix applet that would convert consecutive numbers into a range, so you would have to write something. Ideally, I would use something more math-friendly than bash, but still with good string processing to do it, such as python.

Comment: @GemTaylor: You only need the possibility to split a string with a separator and numerical comparison possibilities.

Comment: @chuck: this might help: [In Bash, how to convert number list into ranges of numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13708705/3776858)

Comment: @Cyrus: thanks for the list2range function! What I did was to split out the two number list cols into two files, then process them into ranges using a bash script calling the function, then replace the two cols with the ranges. A little tedious, but this solved the one-time problem quickly :).

Comment: @Cyrus Yes, it is /possible/ with bash, but unless you find a sample that does it, which you did, thanks, if you have any choice, choose a different language, is still my view.